# Is a function callback in Java also an anonymous class?

Tags: java

For example in this code snippet:

```
c.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Mouse entry event: " + e
                       + " on button: " + buttonLabel);
  }
});
```

Is the code block inside the braces of `addMouseListener` declaring an anonymous class of `MouseAdapter()` and then the whole thing is called a '`function callback`', or am I mixing up the terms? What is the difference?

Comment: yep its an anonymous class and its a listener. [There is difference between callback and listener](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/84732/what-is-the-difference-between-callbacks-and-listeners).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

You can implement callback in several ways in Java, anonymous class is a common way, especially before Java 8.

In OO , callback is relative to a principle called **[Hollywood Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_principle)**: "Don't call us, we'll call you". Check [here](http://cleancodedevelopment-qualityseal.blogspot.jp/2012/10/understanding-callbacks-with-java.html) for more information about callback in java.

In Java, we only have class/object, so, callbacks will always be implemented using objects in Java. Thus, I don't think we should call it "function callback" in Java, instead, callback object may be more appropriate.

We pass a callback object to another object, so that that object can call some specific method on the callback object when that object thinks it is time. In your case, you pass a `MouseAdapter` instance to your `c`. And c will call the method `mouseEntered` of the passed `MouseAdapter` instance when mouse is entered(c thinks it is time). So, we don't explicitly call c'method relative to mouse entered like:

```
while(true){
    if(mouce_entered){
         mouseEntered();
     }
    wait_for_mouseentered_event();
}
```

Instead, `c` does all this job, we only need to pass a callback object to him and let `c` control the logic flow.

1.So, actually, the first way to implement this callback is you declare a class extends MouseAdapter

```
public class YourMouseListener extends MouseAdapter() 
{
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { ... } 
}
```

then create an instance and pass to it:

```
  c.addMouseListener(new YourMouseListener());
```

2.To minimize code and class declared, Java enable you to use anonymous class to achieve callback like:

```
c.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Mouse entry event: " + e
                       + " on button: " + buttonLabel);
  }
});
```

3.In Java 8, we have lambda expression, we can replace some anonymous class into a more concise lambada expression, but this is limited on function interface,which only have one method.

```
//Old way:
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("The button was clicked using old fashion code!");
    }
});

//New way:
button.addActionListener( (e) -> {
        System.out.println("The button was clicked. From lambda expressions !");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will create an anonymous class. You can even see the class file after you compile the code. This happens because there are no "first class" functions (or lambdas) in Java (at least before Java 8, but they still might create anonymous classes).

Comment: So is there a difference? Can you get function callbacks which are NOT anonymous classes, for example?

Comment: In Java there is no difference. Java 8 has syntax sugar that makes this nicer, but it will still create a class.

Comment: Of course you can create function callbacks which are not anonymous classes. Simply create explicit classes instead, like this: `class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter() { public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { ... } } c.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());` As Java programmers we tend to only use explicit classes if there is a (somewhat, subjective) good chance of reuse.